# getLockHolders returns a java.util.Vector how do you unlock for a specific user

Tags: javascript, locking, xpages

var lockHolders:java.util.Vector = document.getLockHolders()

returns a list of current lock holders. I need to unlock the document which is pretty simple if lockHolders[0] == currentUser
However, how do you handle it if the currentUser is one of the names in a multi-value list

```
if (lockHolders[0] == currentUser){
     document.unlock();
}
```

I could remove the currentUser from the Vector list in lockHolders but there is no setLockHolders can I just do a replaceItemValue("LockHolders",lockHolders) ?
I believe that lockHolders generally would be single value, and not sure what conditions would allow for multiple names in the Vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect a lockHolder to contain one value only. After all that's what the lock is meant to do. However if you want to code super defensive try this:

```
 var lockHolders:java.util.Vector = document.getLockHolders();
 for (var curHolder in lockHolders) {
     if (curHolder.toString() === currenUser) {
        document.unlock();
        break;
     }
 }
```

The `Vector` actually returns a set of Objects, so to be sure I use `.toString()`. Then the `===` (yes - three of them) does a comparison without trying to convert data types. If the Vector as expected has one value, the loop runs once. If the document isn't locked (can't recall if the Vector has an empty element or is empty) the loop runs not (if Vector is empty) or once with the comparison false.

Does that work for you?

Comment: This would work, I used 
if (lockHolder.isEmpty){
//do something
}else{
if (lockHolder.contains(currUser)){
//do something else
}
Your code is a bit cleaner